# Efficient way of calling a function and using the result to call another function

Tags: c++, optimization

I am a hobbyist, and am learning some OpenGL for a personal project; I don't have the deepest understanding of c++ (I'm okay with that for now), so I'm sorry if this is a stupid or obvious question.

I'm wondering about the pros and cons of each way of doing the following (if any), assuming this piece of code runs every tick of the game loop:

```
glm::vec3 camera_pos = g_Camera->GetPosition();

some_func(camera_pos.x, camera_pos.y, camera_pos.z);
```

vs:

```
some_func(g_Camera->GetPosition().x, g_Camera->GetPosition().y, g_Camera->GetPosition().z);
```

My hunch is that the 1st version is better for performance since it is only one function call, but I'm not sure if the compiler would be optimizing the 2nd version to make no difference overall?  I'd prefer to use the 2nd version for convenience and readability, but I'd most like to do the more efficient thing.  I'm trying not to do too much premature optimization, but this has been something that I've wondered about for a while now.

Comment: If your question is "does creating intermediate variables negatively effect performance", I'd say no. The compiler will optimize what it can, and may inline it if possible. I'd keep it separate just for the sake of readability. This seems like pre-optimization; even for a game loop.

Comment: The second will probably be optimised but that's up to your compiler, if you're targeting game consoles then the general advice is to just not assume anything. I actually think the first is more readable but I guess that's opinion based, assuming `g_Camera->GetPosition();` returns a const reference to a vector, you could just expose that const reference rather than having a function to return one ( but that might be going a little too far and i'm probably rambling ). TLDR; use whatever you want it probably won't at all matter but the first is more common.

Comment: I wouldn't think about such micro-optimizations up front. Try to write the code first in a way so that it is more concise and readable. You can later run a profiler to determine the real bottlenecks of your game.

Comment: @mjkjr: For these micro-optimization cases it is helpful not to think so much of operations which a compiler can and cannot reduce. Instead consider each individual optimization step as an added complexity for the optimizer to deal with. One or a few is generally fine but there always a threshold beyond which the compiler effectively gives up, which may fail catastrophically if you are unlucky and just inadvertently added the last straw. So for the most part write straightforward and legible code but when dealing with a critical inner loop it is often helpful to be explicit in what you expect.

Comment: @George, Yeah, I am trying to not expose the position vector completely because I only want the camera object itself in charge of directly modifying that value, and I want that to be guaranteed.

Comment: @mjkjr I only suggested to expose a const reference, meaning you won't be able to modify the object through that reference. <- It would guarantee the elimination of the function call, but may based on case be an over optimisation.

Comment: @George, ahh, I see - that is a concept I wasn't aware of, though it seems like my first option above is going to be what I stick with for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever compiler you are using will likely optimize this away. There are cases where it cannot. If, for example, getPosition requires calculation, is not idempotent, or is a virtual call, it may not be able to optimize it.

This probably is not the case here. Use your first version. It's more readable and easier to debug.

When in doubt, you can compile to assembly or something and see if there's any difference

Comment: Thanks, kind of what I figured, but I was just curious if there was any other views about this I might have missed.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could pass the entire result at once.

If `some_func` looked like:

```
void some_func(const glm::vec3& pos) {...}
```

Then you could call it like:

```
some_func(g_Camera->GetPosition());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't, and it isn't my function so I can't change it either.  I'm passing it to an OpenGL library function glUniform3f(GLint location, GLfloat v0, GLfloat v1, GLfloat v2), which doesn't have a version that accepts a vector.